# problems compiling .tex into .pdf under OS X 10.10

Tags: multicol

Background knowledge:
- Using Mactex 2014 with the Latexian editor on OS X 10.10
- Landspace `.tex`-file with 3 columns in the `multicols` environment (-> check code below)

PROBLEM: When I create a `.pdf`-file from my original `.tex`-file with the export function of the Latexian editor (basically it's just compiling my .tex-file), the last column, where I have something written, will be stretched over the entire column. So e.g. if I have two entries, the first one is completely on top of the column and the second entry is on the bottom of the column.

First I thought that the editor had some bugs so I tried creating a `.pdf`-file with TeXworks, but I had the same problem.
Then I switched to my bootcamp partition where I have TeX Live installed. I compiled the file on my win7 partition with TeXworks and everything was fine. The text wasn't stretched and everything worked fine. My conclusion out of my experiences are now that there is probably a problem with the Mactex package or with something else.

Question: Can anyone provide a solution for me, so I can compile my `.tex`-files under OS X again?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pagesize ,landscape, 5pt, fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=0.75cm,right=0.75cm, top=0.75cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\pagestyle{plain}
\columnsep 30pt
\columnseprule .4pt

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}

This is the first entry. \\

This is the second entry. \\

\end {multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should delete the `\\ ` (never end a paragraph with `\\ `) your example works fine for me with texlive 2014 (both lines appear in the first col, one at top, one at bottom) the operating system will make no difference but you may have different package versions. Add `\listfiles` to your preamble and post the list of package versions to your question so we see which versions you have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is indeed a versioning issue

```
TeX live 2013    [2011/06/27 v1.7a  multicolumn formatting (FMi)]  -- correct
TeX live 2014    [2014/04/23 v1.8e  multicolumn formatting (FMi)]  -- bug
version on CTAN  [2014/10/28 v1.8i  multicolumn formatting (FMi)]  -- corrected
```

This is the relevant fix from the change log:

```
2014-10-28    <Frank.Mittelbach@latex-project.org>

    * multicol.dtx: In \end{multicols*} only add vertical space if not
    doing already doing \raggedcolumns and add \null to hide the final
    fill if added so that it doesn't get removed again
```

The 2014 version had a number of improvements and corrections added but unfortunately one of them resulted in removing the added vertical space at the very end of the document. Thus if you got that version your example will show this vertical stretch between the two paragraphs (which it shouldn't).

`\raggedcolumns` isn't really the answer since that applies to the whole environment or document. The correct answer is to update to a correct version.

- if your distribution has some way to refresh packages then get the newest version of multicol this way
- if not, consider getting it from CTAN (you need multicol.dtx and multicol.ins and unpack yourself by running `latex multicol.ins`to obtain the `.sty`file)
- quick option: take the multicol.sty (which is probably the 2011 one) from your windows machine and replace the version you have on MacOS -- not really recommended
- manual option: add `\vspace*{\stretch{1}}` to your document (just before `\end{multicols*}` that should mimic what should happen.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your explanation. Indeed I had v1.8e installed. Updated to v1.8i and the bug disappeared. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @montju in that case you may want to check mark the answer as the one solving your problem

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want the lines to be pulled to the page baseline add `\raggedcolumns` :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pagesize ,landscape, 5pt, fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=0.75cm,right=0.75cm, top=0.75cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\pagestyle{plain}
\columnsep 30pt
\columnseprule .4pt

\begin{document}

\raggedcolumns
\begin{multicols*}{3}

This is the first entry. 

This is the second entry.

\end {multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your quick reply. \raggedcolumns worked fine but I'm still questioning myself, why the compilation of my tex-file works perfectly fine under win7 Tex Live and why I get such a stretched pdf under OS X...

Comment: @montju as I say, add `\listfiles` to the preamble and compare package versions. (There was a new version of multicol this year for example) although being stretched without \raggedcolumns is what I'd expect with any version.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle not a good advice really, David. You should have told him Frank has screwed up and you got a screwed up version. He wants and should get the last column without stretch just by default and that works without \raggedcolumns (as long as you have a correct version :-))

Comment: @FrankMittelbach i think the latex world would be screwed up without your contributions...thank you.

Comment: @doed well isn't there a saying you can#t do anything wrong if you aren#t doing anything? or something along those lines? I certainly made the mistake of fixing a very complex issue or two with multicol this year and unfortunately it too a few iterations to weed out the boundary cases I overlooked. In fact there is on other one that needs fixing and will result in yet another CTAN release soon :-(